# How can I draw a region of interest on an image in Julia?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, julia, image-segmentation

I am trying to write code that segments a certain portion of an image based on the shape I draw over it. Basically, I want to draw a rectangle over the image and that rectangle is the input for my segmentation function which will carry out segmentation based on my trained model. I have been looking at GLMakie and Images but I can't seem to find a way to achieve it. I am experienced in python but am new to Julia.

It would really help if someone could tell me what package I can use or any other means to get this done in Julia.

Comment: @john_sambayal not familar with julia...but perhaps this might help https://github.com/JuliaImages/Images.jl

Comment: I am familiar with the Images package. Right now I'm looking at this package called GLMakie. Demonstrations for that package show that it might be possible. But being a beginner, I'm having a hard time going through the documentation and figuring out how to do it. Once I figure out I'll definitely update the post. Thanks!